# Java: Change detection

Tags: java

I have the following design where I need to interact with client's API. And the `WatchService` (or Change Detection Handler method) had to be in the `Testing` Class in this caseand not in the `FoodOrder` class or `ClientAPI` class.

The `ClientAPI` class receives food orders from the various food machines via a callback method. All food orders have a unique reference number and are stored in a hashmap. Now when there is an update in `instructions` for the same food order (identified by the same reference number), a "change" is detected and new instruction is written to a file. The creation / modification of file will be picked up by the `WatchService` in the `Testing` class and trigger the `proceesInstruction` method to read the updated instructions.

I am looking for a better way to detect the change and pass the updated instructions to the `Testing` class without reading and writing to file, replacing the `WatchService` entirely, as this is very clumsy?

```
Class Testing{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        // connect to API...
        ClientAPI clientAPI = new ClientAPI();
        clientAPI.connect();

        /*** Starting WatchService ***/
        WatchService watchService = null;
        try {
            watchService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        scheduler.schedule(new WatchFile(watchService), 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }


    private static class WatchFile implements Runnable{
        
        WatchService watchService;
        public WatchFile(WatchService watchService) {
            this.watchService = watchService;
        }
        
        
        public void run() { 
            try {
                System.out.println("2. WatchService Started Running @ " + LocalDateTime.now() + " !!!");
                Path path = Paths.get("C:\\Testing\\csv");
                path.register(watchService, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE,StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY,StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE, StandardWatchEventKinds.OVERFLOW);
                WatchKey key;
                while((key = watchService.take()) != null) {
                    for(WatchEvent<?> event: key.pollEvents()) {
                        final Path changed = (Path) event.context();
                        if(changed.endsWith("newInstructions.csv") && event.kind() == StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY) {
                            System.out.println("Instruction File modified!!!");
                            processInstruction("C:\\Testing\\csv\\newInstructions.csv");
                        }
                    }
                    key.reset();
                }

            } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 

        }
    }

    public static void proceesInstruction(string filePath){
        // read the csv file path and process instruction
    }

}

Class FoodOrder{
    int machineNumber;
    String item;
    String instruction;
    String referenceNumber;
    public FoodOrder(int machineNumber, String item, String instruction, String referenceNumber){
        this.machineNumber = machineNumber;
        this.item = item;
        this.instruction = instruction;
        this.referenceNumber = referenceNumber;
    }

    public void updateFoodOrder(int machineNumber, String item, String instruction, String referenceNumber){
        this.machineNumber = machineNumber;
        this.item = item;
        this.referenceNumber = referenceNumber;

        // Detect change in instruction
        if(!instruction.equals(this.instruction)){
            // my original code writed the new instruction to the 
            // C:\\Testing\\csv\\newInstructions.csv such that watchservice can detect file has been modified or created
            // and process the instructions in the csv
        }
        this.instruction = instruction;

    }


}



Class ClientAPI{
    private HashMap<String,FoodOrder> foodOrderHashMap;
    
    // Constructor
    public clientAPI(){
            foodOrderHashMap = new HashSet<String,FoodOrder>();
    }

    // API callback function 
    public void receiveMachineOrder(int machineNumber, String item, String instruction, String referenceNumber){
        // my original is to write the instruction 
        if(foodOrderHashMap.containsKey(referenceNumber)){
            foodOrderHashMap.get(referenceNumber).updateFoodOrder(machineNumber,item,instruction,referenceNumber);
        } else{
            foodOrderHashMap.put(referenceNumber, new FoodOrder(machineNumber, item, instruction, referenceNumber));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So what you are doing is asynchronous processing of an incoming (synchronous) request. This is very well handled with a [producer - consumer - approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem). `FootOrderService` is a producer of `FootOrderInstruction` message, passed via a queue to `InstructionProcessor`. There are plenty of messaging middleware solutions and libraries out there implementing [JMS](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html) as the API standard.

Comment: It is not clear why you are mixing a scheduler with a watcher. I would not use the scheduler, but have the watcher run continuously in a new thread. When the watcher sees a file change have it alert the main thread.

Comment: @SME_Dev forgive me for my poor explanation and question . Would  the JMS or producer consumer design stop the client API’s callback function from returning messages when the consumer is waiting for the producer ?

Comment: No. The `ClientAPI` responds almost immediately, because it will only send away the JMS message. It does not matter how long `processInstruction()` will take, because it is happening in another system process. Basically you have 2 separated services.

Comment: @SME_Dev, i came across resources that suggest using Kafka. So JMS or Kafka ?

Comment: Kafka is a bit oversized for your scenario. Think of it like a messaging plattform for several systems or enterprise scope. In your case, you need a queue for a single application, so it's the scope of an implementation detail. ActiveMQ or RabbidMQ were what I had in mind. Also some application servers like JBoss, TomEE, Weblogic, etc. offer build-in queues. So the question is essentially about in which environment are your applications currently running. Chance is there is already some queuing feature available.

Comment: noted. Thanks for the advice. Thing is my program is also collecting real time data in multiple places. This is why i am exploring Kafka for future scalability.

Comment: @SME_Dev The application is going to be running in Window. I have explored kafka and it crashes all the time in Windows. It's just not meant for Windows OS and I agree that it is oversized for my scenario. I would like to ask what would you recommend in this case ?

Comment: and my application is written in JAva, I want something that doesn't crash as often as Kafka in Windows.